# Windows software required to compare 2 folders through the tree to the leafs

Tags: windows, file-management, file-synchronization, file-merging

Actually, I have got 2 versions of a folder which has multiple folders and files and has a max depth of 6, now I am not sure what changes I did in which file and in which version.

**Use Cases**

1. I need a tool that would list all the files that do not match
2. Then on clicking on the changed file, it shows the changes, similar to Diff in svn

I can do the second use case manually though a stand-alone comparison tool, but I can't find software which meets the first use case.

Answer (score 10):

I suggest you use [Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) (if for Windows).

First you do a directory compare which let you quickly check which files/folders are missing/newer/different:

[image]

With the file copy/move operations you can bring complete files in sync.

Then you do a file contents comparison, and when in edit mode you can copy the different fragments from file to file:

[image]

You can use the fully functional shareware version, or $40.- / €32.- will get you a life-long registration.
I *live* in this program because of its ton of other features.

Comment: From the Total Commander web page:  "Total Commander for Windows is a Shareware (demo version) program. This means that you can test it for a period of 30 days. After testing the program, you must either order the full version, or delete the program from your harddisk."

Comment: @JerryD I overlooked that, sorry. I just paid for it.

Answer (score 6):

I recommend [KDiff3](http://kdiff3.sourceforge.net/) which is available for Windows, OS X, and Unix. It's freely available (GPLv2). *Its comparison capabilities are excellent!* Below is a screenshot from comparing two Linux kernel source code directories:

[image: Screenshot of KDiff3]

The file view in the screenshot is displaying both common and different files, but it is trivial to filter and let it only show files that are different/only present in one directory.

Answer (score 5):

On Unix, OS X and Windows you can use [Meld](http://meldmerge.org/):

- free and open-source
- Two- and three-way comparison of files and directories
- File comparisons update as you type
- Auto-merge mode and actions on change blocks help make merges easier
- Visualisations make it easier to compare your files
- Supports Git, Bazaar, Mercurial, Subversion, etc.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

*Assuming Windows*

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/) is a great diff program and can do exactly that. WinMerge is both free and open source.

- *Use Case 1:* Just select the two folders in the comparison dialogue and then sort by `comparison result` (see screenshot for example)
- *Use Case 2:* Just double click on any of the files there to see the diff for that specific file - or select two files in th compare dialogue and it'll compare those. 
  [image: screenie]

Comment: Unfortunately, WinMerge does not show whether a folder contains differences or not (recursively). Or at least I have not found any way to make it show that. This problem makes WinMerge a pain to use for a "tree to leafs" comparizon in 6-levels hierarchies.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [Total commander](http://www.ghisler.com), it has special subtree comparison tool in menu `Commands` > `Synchronize Dirs...`:

[image]

I'm using it to compare/sync projects with 100,000 files in tree of 8,000 directories.

Checkboxes:

- **Assymmetric**

  - disabled = left and right side are equal
  - enabled = left side is source, right side is target so file deletions on right side can be generated (see rows with red X on demo image)
- **Subdirs** - also compare subdirectories
- **By content** - also compare files by content (byte-by-byte)
- **Ignore date** - compare files only by name and size (an by content, if checked)

Other controls:

- [image] - toggle buttons to show/hide categories of items
- middle column of main list – sync of each file can be individually customized. **Synchronize** button starts sync based on selections made in this column.

Notice that in my demo image, in left pane there is a ZIP archive.

In the main list, each line can be evaluated individually:

- <kbd>F3</kbd> - show left file
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> - show right file
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> - run line-by-line compare tool (including editor). Its screeshot might be included in another answer.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux you can use [Krusader](http://www.krusader.org/):

- free and open-source
- list all the files that do not match
- can [compare](http://www.krusader.org/documentation/compare.html) files by content via external diff programs like Kompare, KDiff3 or xxdiff.

[image]

[image]

Comment: looks like "inspired" by Total Commander :)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and ran across this article on [**How to diff two folders from a Windows command prompt**](https://improvingsoftware.com/2013/09/09/how-to-diff-two-folders-from-a-windows-command-prompt/). This uses Microsoft's **RoboCopy** utility which is *included* in Windows Vista and up. It works with both local folders and network fileshares.

The command is:

> **ROBOCOPY “\FileShare\SourceFolder” “\FileShare\ComparisonFolder” /e /l /ns /njs /njh /fp /log:reconcile.txt**

The article actually suggests that you also use the **/ndl** switch to keep the size of the logfile down *HOWEVER* it warns that when the /ndl switch is active...

> - *Folders that exist only on source or destination are not logged unless at least one mismatched file is present or a source file is missing on destination.*
> - *Folders that exist only on the destination are not logged at all regardless of contents.*

Note that all files and folders are compared with or without using /ndl but what is *logged* is what changes.

Microsoft's webpage explaining the RoboCopy syntax and options is located at:
 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc733145.aspx